# Hide classes in Matlab similar to private functions

Tags: matlab, class, private

[Private functions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/private-functions.html) in Matlab are functions stored in a folder with the name "private" and they are only available to the functions immediately above this folder.

I tried the same for classes but Matlab 2016b refused with

> A class definition may not be in or below a private directory.

I'm writing a toolbox and I want some internal classes not to be visible within Matlab itself, e.g. they should not appear in the search path, similar to how private behaves for classes in Java or how private functions in Matlab behave.

Is there a way and if so, how can it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to make a class private in MATLAB. What you can do though, is to place it in a sub-package and it will therefore be placed in a separate namespace from the rest of your package.

```
+mypackage
    +internal
        myclass.m
```

If you want to remove the requirement that you type `internal` for all your internal functions that need access to your class, you could add a wrapper function in your `private` folder

**`+mypackage/private/myclass.m`**

```
function obj = myclass(varargin)
    obj = mypackage.internal.myclass(varargin{:});
end
```

If you really want to restrict use of the class by anything outside of your package you could put some logic within the constructor to ensure that the calling class is a member of your package

```
classdef myclass < handle
    methods
        function self = myclass()
            % Get the path to the package folder
            directory = fileparts(fileparts(mfilename('fullpath')));

            % Ensure that the function/class that called this was part of te toolbox
            S = dbstack('-completenames');
            assert(numel(S) > 1 && strfind(S(2).file, directory), ...
                'Class only able to be called from the toolbox')
        end
    end
end
```

**Update**

As mentioned by @SamRoberts in the comments, you can also put your constructor within a method block with it's `Access` [restricted to members of the class](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/selective-access-to-class-methods.html#btb03uh). You would need to specify each of the classes that you would like to be granted access

```
classdef myclass
    methods (Access = {?mypackage.Class1, ?mypackage.Class2})
        function self = myclass()
            % Constructor
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: myclass can still be found in the search path, but at least in the namespace and togehterh with the limit of the instantiation to members of the package this fully answers my question.

Comment: @Trilarion As far as I am aware, there is no way to remove it from your search path.

Comment: Instead of the hack using `dbstack`, you could instead restrict the `Access` attribute of the constructor to particular classes in your package - for example, by putting it in a methods block like `methods (Access = ?mypackage.myOtherClass)`. This won't give you package-level privacy exactly (you can't use `Access = ?mypackage`), but restricting access to another class is usually what you _really_ wanted anyway. You can specify multiple classes using `Access = {?mypackage.myClass1, ?mypackage.myClass2}` etc.